# hitTest not working in SceneKit / ARKit

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I set up a tapGestureRecognizer to detect taps of an object in an ARSceneKit scene. The hitTest method that I set up in the handleTap method works fine when I'm very close to the object, but when I get farther away the hitTest method always fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a ridiculous amount of time fiddling with this, I finally tried turning off `ARSCNDebugOptionShowFeaturePoints` on my scene view. I guess the stupid little feature points were getting in the way of the hitTest method.

Comment: Did you check to even see if a node was generated?  Also, what is your hitTest option?  I have found that as of beta 4, the hitTest with extent is some what bugged (Also holding the phone (iPhone SE) landscape with the camera facing right was bugged too, but camera left worked fine)

Comment: Have you found a workaround except turning off feature points?